# Calculate Lat/Long and Distance between Points on a SVG Map

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps

This is what I'd like to achieve for a web-based Gameshow: The contestants will see a map of europe / some part of the world and have to pinpoint a certain location on said map (no scrolling/zooming). Then, I want to calculate the distance between the searched location and each of the contestants points. The one closer to the actual location is going to win.

For the map, I'd like to use a PNG or SVG map, for example like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_political_map_Europe_in_2006_WF.svg)
. I was looking into using a library like d3.js, but found it too complex for this fairly simple task and I hope that it's achievable without it.

So what would be the *easiest* way to achieve this using Javascript/Node.js? To be clear: This doesn't have to be 100% accurate. It should be easy to implement and pretty accurate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *'...pretty accurate'* I doubt you may get one as based on projection type and specific longitude/latitude range, same number of pixels on the image may correspond to different distances, so just an image seems to be not enough

Comment: If you're simply trying to determine which distance is the smallest, then you can just take the hypotenuse of a right triangle formed by the latitude/longitudinal distance between the origin and target. However, since the earth is spherical, this is only going to be fairly accurate at small distances. For all distances, you can use Clairaut's relation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation)

Comment: What you need to do is find the minimum possible distance for all vertices of a country's shape, in order to see which contestant had the most accurate guess.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. Based on that, I'll take a look at d3.js again, as they offer APIs to handle differences with projections and stuff like that. Thank you.